# How to add an attribute value to magento grid or list product view

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have an attribute that currently is appeared into the product page.

How can i add it to product grid and list view in categories?

How can i add it to widgets grid view too? (such as latest products etc)

Magento version is 1.8.1.0

Comment: You will have to override the core magento grid block with a custom extension.

Comment: Can you give me some info of which files shoud i modify?(phtml,xml,controller files too maybe...?) If you ve already done it and have sample code i would appreciate it. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the attribute is add to the product flat table in `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/missing-attributes-on-product-list

Then modify your phtml accordingly

> /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml